# An odd Grid style

Tags: style, grid-layouts

Consider the following grid

```
n = 10;
Grid[{{"Matrix", SpanFromLeft},
  RandomInteger[n, n], RandomInteger[n, n]},
 Frame -> All, Alignment -> Center]
```

[image]

Is there any "clever" way of getting the following layout

[image]

so that the length of the "backline" is always adjusted according to `n`

[image]

and, without the main frame, I'd get

[image]

I know about `FontVariations` and though about using `"StrikeThrough"` over an empty string, but couldn't make it work. Maybe customizing a divider's position? Any ideas?

**Edit:** going one step further, what about something like

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`ItemSize >> Properties and Relations`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ItemSize.html):

- ***"Controls and graphics will by default expand to fit the available area."***

So we can use a graphics object as the title row:

```
ClearAll[addTitleRow]
addTitleRow[ttl_,  lineStyle_: Automatic, textStyle_: Automatic, pos_: {.5, 0}] :=
   PadRight[
     Prepend[{Graphics[{lineStyle /. 
            Automatic -> Directive[Gray, Thickness[Tiny]], Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}],
          Black, Text[Style[ttl, textStyle /. Automatic -> 14, 
            Background -> White], pos]}, 
        ImagePadding -> 0, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
        ImageSize -> {Scaled[1.03], All}, AspectRatio -> 1/20]}] @ #, 
     Automatic, SpanFromLeft] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
n = 10;
mat = {RandomInteger[n, n], RandomInteger[n, n]};

Grid[addTitleRow["  matrix  "] @ mat, 
 Alignment -> {Center, Center}, ItemSize -> {3, 1}, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

```
Grid[addTitleRow["  matrix  "] @ mat, 
  Alignment -> {Center, Center}, ItemSize -> {3, 1}, Frame -> {True, {False, {True}}}]
```

[image]

```
Grid[addTitleRow["  matrix  "] @ mat,  
  Alignment -> {Center, Center}, ItemSize -> {3, 1}]
```

[image]

```
Grid[addTitleRow["  matrix  ", 
   Directive[Orange, AbsoluteThickness[12], CapForm["Butt"]], 
   Directive[Blue, 18], {.15, 0}] @ mat, 
 Alignment -> {Center, Center}, ItemSize -> {3, 1}, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Replace `Frame -> All` with `Frame -> {True, {False, {True}}}` to get

[image]

Remove the option `Frame -> ..` to get

[image]

```
mat2 = {RandomInteger[n, 2 n], RandomInteger[n, 2 n]};

Grid[addTitleRow["  matrix  "] @ mat2, 
 Alignment -> {Center, Center}, ItemSize -> {2, 1}, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant answer, this is exactly what I'm looking for. I just noticed that the "matrix" row's height scales with `n`. Any easy fix for this?

Comment: @samwolfe, maybe changing `ImageSize->..` to `ImageSize -> {Scaled[1.03], Scaled[1]}`  and `AspectRatio ->..` to `AspectRatio -> Dimensions[#][[1]]/(4 Dimensions[#][[2]])`?

Answer (score 8):

A first thought of how approach the problem.

```
n = 10;
itemSize = 1.5;
Column[{
  Grid[{
    {"", " Matrix ", ""},
    {"", SpanFromAbove, ""}
    },
   Frame -> All,
   ItemSize -> n/itemSize,
   Alignment -> {Center, Center},
   Dividers -> {False, {False, {2 -> True}}}],
  
  Grid[{
    RandomInteger[n, n],
    RandomInteger[n, n]},
   ItemSize -> itemSize,
   Frame -> None,
   Alignment -> Center]
  },
 Alignment -> Center]
```

[image]

I set up a `Column` of 2 `Grid`s.

The first, `Grid` enables you to center your label, "Matrix", and to generate horizontal lines to each side of it using `Grid`'s option, `Dividers`.

I've set up a variable `itemSize = 1.5` and use it in the 2nd `Grid` to establish a known fixed width for each column in the 2nd `Grid`.

In the 1st `Grid`, I set a simple relationship between your `n` and the 1st `Grid`'s `ItemSize` option.

You could certainly do this more elegantly and more comprehensively.
This works on my machine with `n >= 7`, but it would benefit from more  thought.

Essentially:

- breakup the problem into smaller bits.
- control things that matter (e.g., `ItemSize->n/itemSize`).
- establish a relationship between the smaller bits.

If the above looks promising, you could try controlling the `ItemSize` in the 1st `Grid` for each of its 3 columns.

Comment: Thanks! I noticed that there is some offset on those dividers for some big enough `n`. Interesting approach nonetheless. Maybe I can work around that somehow.